# Modal Form Validation in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I'm using twitter bootstrap and trying to put validations on my modal form.

Where did I go wrong?

I tried `<form role="form">` but it ain't work.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-custom1 btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reserveModal">Reserve Product</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="reserveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reserveModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reserve Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- FORM -->
          <form id="frm_reserve" name="frm_reserve" class="horizontal">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputRName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputRName" id="inputRName" placeholder="Your Name" data-placement="top" required autofocus>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="textArea" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="textAddress" id="textAddress" placeholder="Your Address"></textarea>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputlName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputREmail" id="inputREmail" placeholder="email@you.com" required >
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputlName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Contact No.</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputRContact" id="inputRContact" placeholder="09XX-XXX-XXXX" required >
            </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          </form>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#reserveModal').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',
    icon: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        inputRName: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Your name is required'
                }
            }
        },
        textAddress: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Your address is required'
                }
            }
        },
        inputREmail: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Your email is required'
                }
            }
        },
        inputRContact: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Your contact number is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
   });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm open for suggestions too.

ADDED `$(document).ready(function()` for clarity.

Comment: Why is it not working? What are the errors you get? Does any part of it work?

Comment: Did you import the plugin? `formValidation` isn't part of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Possible and common reason the validation not working when using `formValidation plugin` with `framework: 'bootstrap'` is mostly forget to include `bootstrap.js` OR `bootstrap.min.js` which comes with `formValidation` plugin Where this file is required for `formValidation plugin` to work with bootstrap framework.

> Don't confuse bootstrap(.min).js file provided by the Bootstrap framework with bootstrap(.min).js provided by FormValidation which is placed inside the formvalidation/dist/js/framework directory.
>
> They are two different files and both of them need to be included.

Reference Can be [Found Here](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#including-library) and Which Libraries to include when using `formValidation plugin` with bootstrap framework

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reserveModal').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    excluded: ':disabled',
    icon: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      inputRName: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Your name is required'
          }
        }
      },
      textAddress: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Your address is required'
          }
        }
      },
      inputREmail: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Your email is required'
          },
          emailAddress: {
            message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
          }
        }
      },
      inputRContact: {
        validators: {
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Your contact number is required'
          },
          regexp: {
            message: 'The phone number can only contain the digits, spaces, -, (, ), + and .',
            regexp: /^[0-9\s\-()+\.]+$/
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/css/formValidation.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-custom1 btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reserveModal">Reserve Product</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="reserveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reserveModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Reserve Product</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- FORM -->
        <form id="frm_reserve" name="frm_reserve" class="horizontal">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputRName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputRName" id="inputRName" placeholder="Your Name" data-placement="top" required autofocus>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="textArea" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Address</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="textAddress" id="textAddress" placeholder="Your Address"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputlName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputREmail" id="inputREmail" placeholder="email@you.com" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputlName" class="col-xs-6 control-label">Contact No.</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputRContact" id="inputRContact" placeholder="09XX-XXX-XXXX" required>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

[Fiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4sud04Lc/1/)